# Irrational sequences whose sum is an even number

Tags: number-theory

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/why-is-e-pi-sqrt163-almost-an-integer), one can see that the sum of two irrationals can yield an integer. Specifically a Lucas number can be expressed as

$$
L_n = \alpha^n + \beta^n,
$$

for $\alpha=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ and $\beta=(1-\sqrt{5})/2$ with $n$ integer (the Fibonacci numbers are somehow complementary to this, so I will not count it as an answer). I was just wondering, are there other "famous" numbers such that their sum is an integer, i.e. that the sum of two irrationals yields an even number?

Comment: There's a lot of them. You can consider, for example $(1+\sqrt{2})^n + (1-\sqrt{2})^n$. Do you see how you can generalize this?

Comment: This is too vague.  Any time you have a quadratic of the form $x^2+2nx+m$ which does not factor over $\mathbb Q$, the roots pass your test.  As do $\pi$ and $-\pi$, for example.  Or $e, 2n-e$.

Comment: Perhaps I should add that one of the numbers does not go to zero for $n$ big.

Comment: Easy to find quadratic examples that meet that condition as well.    Just pick your favorite quadratic irrational with norm $>1$ and consider $\alpha^n, \overline {\alpha}^n$.

Comment: I don't understand what you say...

Comment: Say your favorite quadratic irrational is $3+2i$.  Then $a_n=(3+2i)^n+(3-2i)^n$ is always an even integer.

Comment: Mmm but these are not real...

Comment: You didn't specify that.  If your favorite quadratic irrational is $3+2\sqrt {7}$  then $a_n=(3+2\sqrt {7})^n+(3-2\sqrt 7)^n$ is always an even integer.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/906978/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/48533/242) for simple proofs that make obvious the quoted result (and its natural generalization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very general let $p,q$ be two roots of
$$Ax^2+Bx+c=0 \implies Ap^2+Bp+C $$ $$\implies A C_1p^{n+2}+ B C_1 p^{n+1}+C C_1p^n=0~~~(1)$$
Similarly, we have
$$AC_1q^{n+2}+ B C_2 q^{n+1}+ C C_2 q^n=0~~~~(2)$$
Adding (1) and (2), we get
$$A f_{n+2}+Bf_{n+1}+Cf_{n}=0,$$
where $$f_n=C_1 p^n+ C_2 q^{n}.$$

Comment: Deriving recurrences for sums of powers is clearer in operator language, e.g. see [this remark](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1253368/242)

Comment: But this is more elementary.

Comment: Arguable, since using shift operators is comprehensible at high-school level, and it is much more general. In any case this is already in tens (if not hundreds) of prior answers so you should link instead of duplicating it yet again.